# Apache: I cannot set full cache header for text/html using htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, cache, http-headers

I had a similar problem where I couldn't set the full cache header for JS and CSS files in my htaccess file, and it turned out I couldn't because the cache expiry was being set on the server and I had to add AllowOverride all in the vhost container to get it working, but I still cannot set the full cache header for text/html on a page. I can set the max-age using mod_expires in my htaccess file, but if I try to set a cache header with this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate, public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

The no-cache, must-revalidate, public doesn't show up. The only thing that shows in cache-control is the max-age. Does anyone know how to fix this so I can set the entire cache header in the htaccess for text/html?

Here is what I have after Bob's suggestion and it still doesn't work:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate, public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm trying to set the cache header for the file that is called "/" in the DevTools > Network with initiator "document" and type "html".

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems incorrect. At the moment it only matches files named `.html` , `.htm` etc. and not what you probably intended, all files with the .html extension.

Try:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm trying to set the cache header for the file that is called "/" in the DevTools > Network with initiator "document" and type "html". Only the max-age will show in cache-control, which is set with mod_expires, and not the: no-cache, must-revalidate, public.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do what I was trying to do. You don't actually specify a file type. It's confusing because you can set the max-age for this using the text/html type with mod_expires.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, no-cache, must-revalidate, public"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</IfModule>
```